# Can I use display none for rel statements in jquery or javascript, or just css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a piece of code

```
<li id="node_8" rel="default" class="xx"></li>
```

Is there an automatic way of finding all statements were `rel="default"`, and either stop this from firing, or remove via css.

Would I need to use `livequery`, or jquery `live`.

Comment: Post some relevant code and make you question more clear

Comment: You should not be using something like `rel="default"` in the first place. `rel` is not some attribute that you give arbitrary values to and stick into arbitrary elements.

Comment: thank you code paradox for adding that code. Why would it not show for me. I tried to tab, and put 4 spaces but nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Just try something like the following to find elements with `rel=default`:

```
$('[rel=default]')
```

To remove all elements with `rel=default`, call [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide):

```
$('[rel=default]').remove();
```

**To hide**

You can use jQuery [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide) method like:

```
$('[rel=default]').hide();
```

Comment: what would I add. Would I create a css class with display:none. I am struggling with the syntax. Sorry if may be a little simple.

Comment: @user1498809 what is you main aim? remove them from document or hide them or else?

Comment: Either really they are dontained within li elements. For some reason this will not allow me to add code.  <li id="node_8" rel="default" class="xx"></li> so it is basically remove the whole line really.

Comment: @user1498809 why were you asking for a js solution if you don't need it? CSS3 has a selector like `[rel=default]`, if it is what you want.

Comment: Found out that rel satements can be used in css. ie li[rel~='default'] {display: none ;}, any li that contains rel statement = to default will not be diaplayed.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that rel satements can be used in css. ie `li[rel~='default'] {display: none ;}`, any li that contains rel statement `=` to default will not be displayed. –